# Join list column with string column in PySpark

Tags: list, apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two data frames like `df_emp` and `df_dept`:

`df_emp`:

```
id Name
1   aaa
2   bbb
3   ccc
4   ddd
```

`df_dept`:

```
dept_id dept_name employees
1              DE    [1, 2]
2              DA    [3, 4]
```

The expected result after joining:

```
dept_name employees employee_names
       DE    [1, 2]     [aaa, bbb]
       DA    [3, 4]     [ccc, ddd]
```

Any idea how to do it using simple joins or udf's?

Comment: Try exploding the Dept table on employees column, then join on the exploded column and then use collect_set on both employees and employee_names grouped by dept_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done without UDF. First [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) the array, then join and group.

Input data:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df_emp = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 'aaa'),
     (2, 'bbb'),
     (3, 'ccc'),
     (4, 'ddd')],
    ['id', 'Name']
)
df_dept = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 'DE', [1, 2]),
     (2, 'DA', [3, 4])],
    ['dept_id', 'dept_name', 'employees']
)
```

Script:

```py
df_dept_exploded = df_dept.withColumn('id', F.explode('employees'))
df_joined = df_dept_exploded.join(df_emp, 'id', 'left')
df = (
    df_joined
    .groupBy('dept_name')
    .agg(
        F.collect_list('id').alias('employees'),
        F.collect_list('Name').alias('employee_names')
    )
)
df.show()
# +---------+---------+--------------+
# |dept_name|employees|employee_names|
# +---------+---------+--------------+
# |       DE|   [1, 2]|    [aaa, bbb]|
# |       DA|   [3, 4]|    [ccc, ddd]|
# +---------+---------+--------------+
```